# Need to convert a subquery that selects multiple values to an nhibernate query (criteria or hql)

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, hql, criteria

I have the following query that I need to convert to nhibernate:

```
SELECT  o.* 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN 
(
        -- get the most recent orders based on end_date (this implies the same order can exist in the orders table more than once)
        SELECT o2.order_id, MAX(o2.end_date) AS max_end_date 
        FROM orders o2
        GROUP BY o2.order_id
) most_recent_orders 
                ON o.order_id=most_recent_orders.order_id
                AND o.end_date=most_recent_orders.max_end_date
-- of the most recent orders, get the ones that are complete                
WHERE o.is_complete=1
```

I know hql doesn't support joining to subqueries which is why this doesn't work.  I can't use an "in" statement because the subquery is selecting 2 values.  I tried using the suggestion from hibernate documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-tuple

```
from Cat as cat
where not ( cat.name, cat.color ) in (
    select cat.name, cat.color from DomesticCat cat
)
```

But this threw an error because Sql Server doesn't like multiple values in an "in" statement.

Any help would be appreciated!  I'm open to solutions using Criteria or Hql.

Answer (score 0):

this is using a subquery to achieve the same

```
var maxDateQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<Order>()
    .Add(Restrictions.PropertyEq("OrderId", "order.OrderId"))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("EndDate"));

var results = session.CreateCriteria<Order>("order")
    .Add(Subqueries.Eq("EndDate",maxDateQuery))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsComplete", true))
    .List<Order>();
```

Comment: where is "order.OrderId" coming from?  I don't see an alias called "order" anywhere in the query?

Comment: Now it throws an exception because it's treating "order.OrderId" as a string literal instead of interpolating it.  Error: NHibernate.QueryException : Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: Id expected type System.Guid, actual type System.String